# I need to animate a hamburger menu with a hover

Tags: html, css, animation, hover

I'm trying to have an animation when there is a hover on my hamburger menu, I want the lines to "slide" to the right and disappear with a little delay on each and then come back from the left side.

*(I already have an animation for when its clicked)*

```css
.toggle-button {
  width: 60px;
  height: 45px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 45px;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.toggle-button span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <img src="Images/logo.svg" class="svg">
  <div class="hamburger_wrapper">
    <div class="toggle-button">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please update your question with your attempt at solving the problem. This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: So what is the issue? Have you added "hover"?

Comment: Please [edit] the snippet I've edited into your question. Currently, not much is showing since all of the `span`s are positioned absolutely to the same place...